# Add packages to class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

i want to add package how to add it in intellij idea. Is the problem in the beginning of creating a new project ?

Comment: What do you mean, "add package" Do you have a library you're trying to use? Are you trying to access a class in the standard library?

Comment: the tutorial i'm following is not the same as my code in the first line he have package com.codewithmosh;

Comment: Ok, that is the package that your class is in. I think you can just add a package line to the top of your class file and intellij will tell you it is wrong, and offer you some ways to fix it. One is to move your class to a package.

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume you have an existing class, and you want it to be in a package. This is called **refactoring**

- Right click on your class name (Main in this case)
- In the context menu expand the "refactor"
- In the refactor menu select "move to ..."

Then a dialog should appear that lets you enter the name of the package you would like to move your class to.

If it is a new package, it will create a folder and move the source file there.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in file named `Main.java`

Just add two directories named `com` and `codewithmosh`, respectivly inside each other and then move your `Main.java` class inside it.

After that you can add package statement to your code:

```
package com.codewithmosh;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

Direcory structure for your project is:

────project  
   └───com 
      └───codewithmosh
         └───Main.java